# How to redirect to the app if the deeplink url is same url of Google play store apps url (For me it going to play store) but not redirects to the app

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to redirect the Google play store url to the app if it is available in the device. if it not available in the device i need to redirects it to google play store or chrome browser.

```
 https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=my.app.id
```

i have added the intent filter as well.